# Incompatibility between functools.partial and scipy

Tags: scipy, inverse, cdf

I need to pass the inverse of a cdf as an argument to function.
I cannot understand why this does not work:

```
def InvNormal(q,a,b):
    return  norm.ppf(q,a,b)
F_invs = functools.partial(InvNormal,0,1)
```

Doing

```
print(InvNormal(0.3,0,1))
print(F_invs(0.3))
```

I get

```
-0.5244005127080409
-inf
```

Any help is appreciated!
Bernardo

I tried it with different random variables.

Comment: If you add `print(q, a, b)` inside the definition of `InvNormal(q, a, b)`, you'll see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Based on what you said, I solved the problem even without understanding what is going on. I did 
F_invs = functools.partial(InvNormal,a=0,b=1)
and it worked.